# Use llvmpipe instead of softpipe in yocto

Tags: linux, opengl, embedded-linux, ubuntu-12.04, yocto

I have an old x86 machine. I build generic intel-core2-i32 machine configuration and installed yocto on it. Display is very slow.

Ubuntu 12.04 runs smoothly on the same machine. Graphics driver is same on both cases : `gma500_gfx`

Then i looked into glxinfo and found the difference, ubuntu12.04 is using `Gallium on llvmpipe` 
Whereas yocto is using:

```
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: softpipe
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 19.0.3
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 19.0.3
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 19.0.3
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

How can i change the OpenGL renderer string to "llvmpipe" on Yocto and will this help

Comment: Note that both of these are software rendering drivers. One is just a better software driver. If you have a graphics card then you probably have a driver problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should start by checking that llvmpipe driver is actually enabled. The mesa recipe configuration has this suspicious bit (I believe swrast here really means llvmpipe):

```
GALLIUMDRIVERS = "swrast"
# gallium swrast was found to crash Xorg on startup in x32 qemu
GALLIUMDRIVERS_x86-x32 = ""
```

Check the configuration logs or the resulting packages: if llvmpipe is not being built, try removing the last line above and see if that improves things.

Comment: Oops, I've misread your post a bit -- you seem to be on an actual 32 bit hardware. The lines I mentioned are then probably not relevant to you but the general advice is: find out if the correct gallium driver is built and installed.

Comment: i removed /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so and display is working fine. What is the use of this glamor module. Will we have any side effects?